# Gnu - Arm Float to String ( sprintf )

Tags: c, eclipse, arm, printf

I use gnu arm on eclipse ( lpc1769 m3 cortex ). I want to convert float value to string with sprintf but it doesnt work.

I add -u_printf_float to linker option but it is didnt work. 
How can ı solve ?

```
int main(void) {

    InitBoard();

        float flt = 1.1;
        char msg[256];
        sprintf(msg , "number is %.3f ", flt);
        while (1){

            KC_UART_sendstring(LPC_UART0, msg);

            delay_ms(500);
        }
}
```

that's my linker option

-T "C:\Users**username**\Eclipse-workspace\Test_1\ldscript\LPC17xx.ld" -Xlinker --gc-sections -L"C:\Users**username**\AppData\Roaming\xPacks@gnu-mcu-eclipse\arm-none-eabi-gcc\7.2.1-1.1.5.content\arm-none-eabi\lib\thumb\v7-m" -Wl,-Map,"Test_1.map" --specs=nano.specs -u_printf_float

Comment: Does it work with `KC_UART_sendstring(LPC_UART0, "number is 1.100 ");`?

Comment: How do you know that the `sprintf()` "_doesnt work_"?

Comment: program cant execute sprintf and it is stop on this line if ı add u_printf_float to linker option. if ı comment sprintf, it sends number is 1.100 with uart. if ı remove u_printf_float on linker option, program didint stop on sprintf line and execute while(1) and send number is 1.100.

Comment: Do you have specify the print format to `int_FP`? (https://community.nxp.com/thread/44262#comment-375421).
A little secure note: use `snprintf` ;-)

Comment: ı have no librarian tab, so ı cant find where add int_fp.

Comment: The format specifier `%f` expects a `double`, not ` float`. Try `double`.

Comment: Just cast it to double: `sprintf(msg , "number is %.3f ", (double)flt);`

Comment: sorry, ı try replace float with double but it doesnt work again

Comment: Have you included `stdio.h`? How big is your stack?

Comment: Yes, stdio.h is included. ı have no idea for stack size. How can ı check stack size ?

Comment: You need to check the linker script

Comment: __Main_Stack_Size = 1024 ;

Comment: This might be insufficient. You use up a quarter of it only for your `msg`. The `sprintf` is quite demanding as well. Try doubling it.

Comment: ı try increase stack size and redefine msg[50] but it is not working.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

When looking at the [LPC1769 datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/LPC1769_68_67_66_65_64_63.pdf) I don't see any [FPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_unit).

So if **there is no FPU**, how do you manage `floats`?

- buy a new chip which has FPU
- code without float
- [software FPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39810751/how-are-floating-point-operations-emulated-in-software) but note that your program will suffer from performance issues (speed, RAM)

**Code without float**

use divisor and dividend.
Pi is just `unsigned pi_x_1000000 = 3141593;`

then if you want to compute something like a circle perimeter,

`unsigned circumference = (pi_x_1000000 * 2 * radius) / 1000000;`

*Note:* your chip might cost 12$, it is speed/RAM limited, and, depending and what you want to achieve with it, you might consider using other solution than the software FPU. In industry, we do not use floats because costs and performance issues.

Comment: it's a Cortex M3, not M3F!

Comment: what alternatives can i use ?

Comment: If the micro controller doesn't have a FPU, it doesn't mean it can't do floating point operations. Floating-point operations can also be done in software. The compiler specifically supports the options `-mfloat-abi=soft` and `-mfloat-abi=softfp`.

Comment: ...and you don't need to change the code: the compiler will take care of it.

Comment: @GuillaumeD See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html. It is softfp.

Comment: I think the ABI types are called *soft-float* and *hard-float*, but the command line paramters are called *soft*, *softfp* and *hard*. The referred page says: *Permissible values are: ‘soft’, ‘softfp’ and ‘hard’.*

Comment: "softfp" is for hybrid but if you don't have any FPU...
hybrid means FPU and software....
https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/10/9/r1q7pksku2q3gww9rpqef0dnskphtc

Comment: read your link, in the link you gave me: " ‘softfp’ allows the generation of code using hardware floating-point instructions"

Comment: ı try add -mfloat-abi=soft to linker option and no working, in the same way -mfloat-abi=softfp is no working.  
Is it true that I add them to linker options

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to address the actual problem, and it is not clear to me why it is accepted.

Comment: this answer is relevant because @Flamador was interested to use float but he didn't know about the cons of using floats in embedded systems.

Comment: can absolutely emulate fpu in code