# Can std::isfinite(IntegralType) ever return false?

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

According to the documentation of [`std::isfinite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isfinite), the overload `bool isfinite( IntegralType arg )` always casts `arg` to `double` and calls `bool isfinite( double arg )`.

How would this be different from saying *"`bool isfinite( IntegralType arg )` always returns true"*? In other words, under what scenario would `bool isfinite( IntegralType arg )` return false?

Comment: Well that sure makes for [some fun contradictions](https://www.ideone.com/XeUvDZ). (I'm mostly joking as `std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity` is [only really defined for floating types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/infinity)).

Comment: I think [all](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/exp2) float math functions have that `function(IntegralType arg)` overload that casts the argument to double. So I believe for `isfinite` is just to follow the convention (but I do now know why the convention to cast integers to double is there in the first place, maybe to be consistent with C, I guess)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most (all?) other functions in `<cmath>` also accept integers and automatically convert them to `double`s. `std::isfinite` likely does it for consistency.

In theory it could return `false` if the conversion to `double` overflowed, but in practice we don't have large enough integral types. In fact, GCC & Clang with `-O3` (targeting x86-64) appear to replace the call with `true` (even with [`unsigned`]`long long` arguments).

Such an overflow could happen if the integral type is 128 bits wide and the floating-point type is single-precision (32 bits wide), for example `std::isfinite(float(__uint128_t(-1)))` evaluates to `false`, but since `double` is not allowed to be 32-bit ([see comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63586198/can-stdisfiniteintegraltype-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63586198/can-stdisfiniteintegraltype-ever-return-false/63586532?noredirect=1#comment112445032_63586532)), this doesn't matter.

Comment: All - `abs`: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/c.math#cmath.syn-2

Comment: The range of `float`, `double` and `long double` is undefined in C++, so it is theoretically possible on some archaic platform for `double` to be 32-bit and for this to overflow as a result.

Comment: @J.Schultke: The C++ standard inherits from C minimum requirements for `double` that preclude it from being 32 bits. The range and fineness with which it must be able to represent numbers require it to represent more than 2^32 values.

Comment: @EricPostpischil that's wrong. See [N4680](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf) page 71: *"The value representation of floatingpoint types is implementation-defined. [Note: This document imposes no requirements on the accuracy of
floating-point operations;*" Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/34294938/

Comment: @J.Schultke: The accuracy of operations is different from the fineness of representations. And the value representation is the set of bits that holds the value. That is irrelevant to the values represented or the number of them.

Comment: @J.Schultke *"value representation ... is implementation-defined"* This just means that they don't have to be IEEE 754.

Comment: @EricPostpischil that doesn't change the fact that the representation is still implementation defined. Neither a range nor a precision is given by the standard itself. So where does it say in the C++ standard that `double` has to be 32-bits large? Interoperability with C is also not well defined from what I know.

Comment: `std::isfinite(double((unsigned _ExtInt(1024)) -1))` is `false` on clang (but the cast is necessary)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Minor: Would not the need for "requires 10^10" values be "9 * 10^9" values as the lead digit is not zero?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Maybe/sort of. The external decimal floating-point numbers could be denormalized. But, regardless, the decades would overlap, so only 9•10^9 would be introduced with each exponent. The comment has a typo at the start (“C” should be “C++”), so I will enter a new version and delete it anyway.

Comment: In C++ 2017 draft n4659 21.3.6, C++ adopts from C macros describing floating-point types. In 2 1, it incorporates the C 2011 standard by reference. In 5.2.4.2.2, the C 2011 standard specifies requirements for the `double` type: Converting any 10-digit decimal floating-point number to double and back again must produce the original number (`DBL_DIG` must be at least 10). This immediately requires 9•10^9 > 2^32 values, so 32 bits is inadequate. The required exponent span (`DBL_MIN_EXP` to `DBL_MAX_EXP`, at least −37 to +37) multiplies the number of values required. At least 41 bits are needed.